# NDN nfd-status of the forwarder

Tags: nfd

I would like to know how nfd-status in the NDN forwarder works, how it is initiated and how it communicates with the NFD. And if you were to modify it without any changes to the forwarder but still be able to communicate with it, how do you do it?

Thanks;

Alex